# Spring mvc with maven module

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

Currently, I am working on a Spring MVC project and want to divide the project to smaller modules. I have been searching for the info and found this [page](https://github.com/sonatype/maven-example-en/blob/master/chapter-multimodule-web-spring.asciidoc#web). Although this page describes how to build multiple maven module but I think it lacks of configuration information such as: how can I load persistence.xml to my persistence module? How can I read my applicationcontext.xml in service module? In my original code, the web.xml will locate and load the persistence.xml and applicationcontext.xml, but maven module doesn't have web.xml. So do I have to build java configuration class for each module? If anyone can provide basic information of working with multiple maven modules and Spring MVC, I am really thankful for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the whole purpose of creating multiple modules for your project is to isolate the code by its functional parts, then yes, you will want to have separate config files for each deployable instance.  This means that the only place (outside tests) where config files/classes will exist in your project, will be in your web app.  Since your web app is likely using your other modules as dependencies packaged as JARs, config files in those JARs would not be very convenient.

Note: It is possible to bake config files into your other modules, but in my experience, this only causes confusion and headaches down the road.